# How to develop a TabBar based application with a login functionality?

Tags: iphone, ios, authentication, tabbarcontroller

I am developing an application where i need to show a list as a menu(Courses,lessons,grade,logout) to the user. so even before this i need to show a login screen. Only upon successful and valid login i need to re-direct the user to the menu. So i have planned to develop a tabBar based application with 4 tabs. Here i am confused on how to add the login view controller even before the TabBar controller is loaded. I want the first tab to be selected every time. As of now i am adding my **TabBar controller** as a rootviewcontroller to my **AppDelegate window** and then presenting the login view controller as a modal view controller. But the problem here is even before the **Login View controller** is loaded, my courses view controller is loaded because the tabbarcontroller is loaded first. My actual requirement is i need to load the course view controller with the list of courses based on the inputs given in the Login View controller. But loadview of course view controller is loaded even before the load view of login view controller. so my list of courses is always the same irrespective of who logs in. I am confused here on how to move forward...Any suggestion here would be of great help...

Comment: See my [response](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10538091/251513) to a similar question, maybe could helps you.

Comment: @Mat: But the problem here is Apple insists that TabBarcontroller is the rootview controller...In ur answer u mentioned that show the login view controller as the root view controller and later assign the tabbar controller as the rootview controller...and my question here is when i am in login view controller, how can i add the tabbar controller as the root view controller in my login view controller?

Comment: I meant that the first vc view will be your loginVC as rootVC (now there is no tabBar), then you have to swap the rootVC from your loginVC to tabBarVC and load your data based on the user's input. I don't know how Apple can understand who is the rootVC if you start with a window-based template.

Comment: Ur suggestion seems to be valid but can u please provide a sample code snippet or any tutorial link where this is expalined..It would make my understanding clear if i have a look at it..Thanks a lot Mat for ur time. Ur suggestion was really a different idea for me...

Comment: i've provided you a quick example.

Comment: @PradeepReddyKypa u mean u got tabbarview in loginview??? and u want to hide tabbar... and after successfull login u want to show tabbarview.??

Comment: @NSError No. My application is a tabbar based application and i need to add a login view even before the tab bar is loaded...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, a very quick example, could be; in your `loginViewController` you should have some method something like this:

```
//Call this after the user has done with the login
-(IBAction)remove:(id)sender{
    AppDelegate *del=(AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    //Set some data based on the user's input (eg some property shared in the AppDelegate)
    //del.dataEnterByTheUser=someData;
    [del removeLoginView];
}
```

Then in your `AppDelegate` (assuming that **now** the `rootViewController` is the `loginViewController`) you could do like this (you can optimize the transition):

```
-(void)removeLoginView{

    UITabBarController *tabVC=[[UITabBarController alloc] init];
    ViewController *v1=[[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];
    //v1.data=self.dataEnterByTheUser;
    ViewController *v2=[[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];
    NSArray *arrayVC=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:v1,v2, nil];
    [tabVC setViewControllers:arrayVC];
    [tabVC setSelectedViewController:0];
    CGRect rectVC=self.loginViewController.view.frame;
    rectVC.origin.y=self.view.frame.size.height;
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3f delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut animations:^{
        self.loginViewController.view.frame=rectVC;
    } completion:^(BOOL finished){
        [self.loginViewController.view removeFromSuperview];
        self.loginViewController=nil;
        self.window.rootViewController=tabVC;
    }];    
}
```

Also remember to set in each viewControllers's `initWithNibName:` the `self.title` to set the title on the tabItem.

Answer (score 2):

No need to fiddle around with the rootViewController...

Just add the following code at the beginning of your `viewWillAppear:` method of the view controller which would normally appear first (most likely the VC you are presenting in the first tab):

```
[self.tabBarController presentModalViewController:loginController animated:NO];
```

Where loginController is obviously the view controller which manages your login screen. If you show it without animation, it will be the first thing visible when your app launches (after the default image disappears). I've used the same method to show a disclaimer page which the user must read before using the app. It's working just fine and made it to the store without problems.

**Edit:** In this solution, the loginController must dismiss itself once the user has successfully logged in:

```
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO]; //Although you might do this animated, this time
```

Comment: Its totally wrong as the viewWillAppear method will always be called when the tabs are cliked..in my application i have 4 tabs and when the user changes the tab selection, everytime viewWillAppear method is called and everytime the tab is selected the login view controller is called....so this should not be the right way on how to add the login view controller...

Comment: Of course you need to check if showing the login is necessary first. You could do this by setting a value in NSUserDefaults for example. Another reason for not showing the login would be if the app remembers login credentials and the user needs to login at the first launch only. I didn't mention it because I was thinking you'd do something like this anyway...

Answer (score 1):

You can just change the array of view controllers in the tab bar controller at runtime. That should be sufficient for your purposes.

I've written a small example. Try to login with the following credentials:

- username: `john`, password: `doe`
- username: `pete`, password: `poe`

You will see a different combination of tabs depending on the login used.

The example can be downloaded from my Dropbox: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/6487838/LoginTabExample.zip