# Combining different views in one app

Tags: ios, ios7

I am new to iOS development and after prototyping my app flow, I am ready to start building it. All tutorials I went through describe the different types of app templates you could use (tabbed, single view, etc). I need to create a single view with login credentials or sign-up and then once successful, load a tabbed view (much like twitter app).

Any recommendations / tutorial links addressing this (I exhausted by search queries) would be appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: If you wish to have a different navigation hierarchy than what the templates offer, start with the empty templates and create your own hierarchy. :)

Comment: yes that would be a serious option to consider. Nevertheless, suggestion of rootviewcontroller changes throughout seems appealing. going to try it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If You start with a window-based application, You can first set your login viewController as `rootViewController` of the main window and then, after the user has logged in, set the tabBarController as `rootViewController`.

Also take a look at this old question: [How to develop a TabBar based application with a login functionality?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10765364/how-to-develop-a-tabbar-based-application-with-a-login-functionality/10765835#10765835)

Answer (score 1):

You will have to go with `UITabBarController` in that case. That will help you make a Tabbed view across your views. Embedding your views will make all those view have a Tab Bar  at the bottom. Some good links on `UITabBarController` are as follows :

http://www.mysamplecode.com/2013/02/ios-tab-bar-controller-example.html

http://www.iphonedevcentral.com/create-uitabbarcontroller/

Also, do have a look on the [Apple's Documentaion on UITabBarController](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITabBarController_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You could do it by using the following method found in every subclass of `UIViewController`
:

```
[self presentViewController:_loginViewController animated:YES completion:^{
     // Something your app has to do when its done with this login/signup view
}];
```

In order to get rid of the view again call:

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{}]
```

I don't have any links to tutorials for you, but in the [documentation of UIViewController](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/presentViewController%3aanimated%3acompletion%3a) there are some samples that make use of the methods I just described above, that sample code should be fairly easy for you to dissect in order to achieve what you want.